# Converting page range from docx to pdf using pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I'm trying to convert certain pages of a `docx` to `pdf` using pandoc but I can't find any sources hinting at where should I start. After taking a look into the pandoc documentation I still couldn't figure it out, so I just assumed that pandoc doesn't support this.

This might just act as a confirmation for future readers, **Does pandoc support page range converting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc has no concept of pages.

Putting text on pages happens during rendering with Word and LaTeX, but pandoc does not render the text before converting. Therefore it cannot know on which page a specific letter will be placed.